# "[…] which would by the end of the evening, raise nearly two million dollars"

Tags: modal-verbs, verbs, word-meaning

Is the highlighted phrase an indirect way of saying "the auction raised nearly two million dollars"?

> The program featured a cocktail hour—the Top Spin (gin with lime juice), the 40–Love (strawberry liqueur and Prosecco)—followed by dinner, a performance by a mentalist, and a live auction, **which would, by the end of the evening, raise nearly two million dollars**.

**Edit**: The sentence came from [this lengthy piece](http://bbs.hupu.com/6281748.html) about tennis star Novak Djokovic.

Comment: Please, please, PLEASE do not ask about the meaning of passages without including additional information about where you got it from. Imagine me asking the question, "What does **Mary had a little lamb** mean?" without linking to online restaurant review where the author writes: _I went to this delightful little cafe with my friend Mary on a Tuesday evening when the crowds were sparse. I ordered the Coq a Vin; Mary had a little lamb. Both of us found the meals tasty and perfectly seasoned._ Many who want to tackle the problem of literary interpretation appreciate full context – please give it.

Comment: @J.R.- That's awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Would* is used as the past form of *will*.

> He said he would be here at eight o'clock. *He says he will be here at eight o'clock.*

> She asked if I would help. *She asks if I will help.*

Using the Simple Present for *feature*, the quoted sentence would become:

> The program features a cocktail hour—the Top Spin (gin with lime juice), the 40–Love (strawberry liqueur and Prosecco)—followed by dinner, a performance by a mentalist, and a live auction, which will, by the end of the evening, raise nearly two million dollars.

Comment: But eventually this auction earned that right?

Comment: The two million dollars were raised, yes.

Comment: IT is a bit ambiguous whether it is *the program* or *the auction* that raised the 2 million.  Grammatically it should be the auction, but I have a feeling that it's really the *program*.

Comment: @Jim I think it is the auction that raised two million dollars. If it were the program to raise two million dollars, I would expect an _and_ instead of _which_: "The program featured […], and would raise […] two million dollars."

Comment: @kiamlaluno- Like I said, I agree that grammatically it should be *the auction*, but it sounds to me like they are describing a fundraiser that includes the bar, dinner, a show and the auction, and that by the end of the whole evening (in which all those things took place) they will have raised 2 million.  If it's just the auction, why mention all those other potential fundraising activities?

Comment: @Jim Because they are part of the program, but they don't necessarily contribute to the found raising, at least not directly.

Comment: Typically, they *do* count as part of the fundraiser.  The dinners are described as, "$400-a-plate dinners" for example, along with the proceeds raised from bar sales etc.

Comment: http://www.501connect.com/non-profit-news/planning-a-successful-dinner-auction-fundraiser-expert-advice-from-mike-orlando